# Using Owl Slider with WordPress Default Gallery

Tags: javascript, wordpress, owl-carousel-2

For reasons beyond my ability to override, I am forced to use WordPress's default Gallery addition for my site.

I am trying to use Owl Slider to control a "product review" section in my posts.

However, it seems that Owl Slider, and jQuerySlider 2 both work off the elements being used with `<div>` items.

Is there a way to get Owl Slider to utilize the `<dl><dt>+<dd>` elements?

I need to get it looking like product image on the left, description on the right, which I can control easily with CSS, but I need to make sure Owl Slider will work with the elements above. Altering the html output via JavaScript for the Gallery is also not an option as my senior developers hate using any javascript that can be avoided.

Using the code

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery(".gallery").owlCarousel({
    items                   : 1,
    singleItem              : true,
    autoHeight              : true,
    transitionStyle         : "fade",
    stopOnHover             : true,
    pagination              : true,
    responsive              : true,
    responsiveBaseWidth     : window

  });
});
```

I am able to get it to wrap, however it displays every gallery item in a row. I can't link to the page as it's on a development site.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up being able to just add:

```
jQuery(".entry-content .gallery").addClass( 'owl-carousel owl-theme');
jQuery(".entry-content .gallery").owlCarousel( {
        items                   : 1,
        singleItem              : true,
        autoHeight              : true
} );
```

And everything else is included.

This allows for adjustable height on Owl-Slider. I was able to add this to my .js file so that it gets called on any single-post page that has the WordPress Gallery.

Also, I wasn't linking in correctly the .css files.